# How convert base64 to pdf React-Native

Tags: android, ios, reactjs, react-native, base64

I created an app using `react-native` and have some **base64** data from
api. I want convert **base64** data to **pdf** format. if you have any idea
please help me. thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use react-native-pdf package (https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-pdf). If you want to show the pdf in your app , this package would be quite helpful as it supports loading PDFs from base64 string for both ios and android . You can specify the pdf's source from your base64 data as shown in their example :

`{uri:"data:application/pdf;base64,JVBERi0xLjcKJc..."}`

Comment: how do I get the base64 string from the fetch response?

Comment: FYI: does not work with expo

Comment: @ikiK see https://github.com/expo/examples/tree/master/with-pdf

Comment: I have a lot of base64 images, how do you do that?

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming, `converting to PDF` as in `saving the base64 format data as PDF in some file`.

the following code can help you do the same,

```js
let fPath = Platform.select({
   ios: fs.dirs.DocumentDir,
   android: fs.dirs.DownloadDir,
});

fPath = `${fPath}/pdfFileName.pdf`;

if (Platform.OS === PlatformTypes.IOS) {
    await fs.createFile(fPath, base64Data, "base64");
} else {
    await fs.writeFile(fPath, base64Data, "base64");
}
// RNFetchBlob can be used to open the file
```

Comment: Where is the `fs` dependency coming from?

Comment: back then we had something called `react-native-fs`, you could check if that still exists.

Comment: you could check this - https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-fs

Comment: I used this import: `import RNFS from 'react-native-fs';` after it, I can just use `await RNFS.writeFile(path, fileContent, 'base64');`. Reminder: set permissions on iOS and Android! For a "preview only, copy later" approach the `RNFS.DocumentDirectoryPath` can be used. To copy the file to Download folder, I used `await FileSystem.cpExternal(fullPath, fileName, 'downloads');` from `import { FileSystem } from 'react-native-file-access';`. To preview the PDF I used `await FileViewer.open(fullPath)` from `import FileViewer from 'react-native-file-viewer';`

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by using the `rn-fetch-blob` library in React Native. First, make sure to install it:

```bash
npm install rn-fetch-blob
```

Then, create a function to download the file and save it locally.

```js
import RNFetchBlob from 'rn-fetch-blob';

async function downloadFile(url: string, fileName: string /* eg : file.pdf; image.png, document.csv*/) {
  let dirs = RNFetchBlob.fs.dirs;
  let path = `${dirs.DownloadDir}/${fileName}`; //set your path 
 

  try {
    const res = await RNFetchBlob.config({
      fileCache: true,
      addAndroidDownloads: {
        useDownloadManager: true,
        notification: true,
        mediaScannable: true,
        title: fileName,
        path,
      },
    }).fetch('GET', url)
      .then(() => {
     // Do any additional processing or UI updates after successful download if needed

      })
      .catch(() => {
          console.error('Download Error:', error);
    // Handle errors or show a relevant message to the user

      })

  } catch (error) {
    AppSettings.toggleShowProgress()
    console.error('Download Error:', error);
  }

}

// Call the function with the URL and desired file name
downloadFile("https://ou.s3.amazonaws.com/5f50c17SignedHeaders=host", 'file.pdf');
// or
downloadFile("https://picsum.photos/200/300", 'image.jpeg');
```

Make sure to replace the example URLs with your actual API endpoint URLs. The file extension must match the actual format of the file.

This function uses `rn-fetch-blob` to download the file and save it to the device's download directory. You can then use this local file as needed, for example, to display a PDF.